# Make visual studio deploy a folder's content without having to update it in the project

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

In my web project I often have a number of files in my app_data folder. These files can vary from time to time (example translation files get a new language, lucene index gets updated and gets a new file name etc).

Visual studio only adds files to the deployment process if the files are seperately added to the project. So if a file has been added on disk, but not in the project, this file will not be copied to the server...

Is there a way to make VS add *all* files in a folder to the deployment process without me having to update it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a post build event to copy the contents of a folder to the build target.

This should get you started:
http://visualstudiohacks.com/general/customize-your-project-build-process/

Wow I just saw this was asked in 2009...I hope you figured this out already :)

Comment: Heh, thanks for the answer. Since then I changed jobs and here deployment is all done with build systems and automatic deployments

Comment: This answer does not follow the guidelines of stackoverlow. The link does not work any more.